# Spring data mongoDB: Get the distinct rows with pagination

Tags: spring, mongodb, pagination, distinct

I have User class like,

```
@Document(collection = "users")

public class User {

    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String jobTitle;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

And UserDimension as,

```
@Document(collection = "userDimensions")

public class UserDimension{

    private String id;
    private String userId;

    private String dimensionId;

    private String status;
}
```

I want the userDimension records from mongoDB based on distinct userId with pagination in spring data mongoDB ?

I am using the query like,

```
Query query = new Query();

List<UserDimension> userDimensionList = null;

// apply pagination parameters to the search criteria
query.with(pageable);
userDimensionList = mongoTemplate.getCollection("userDimensions").distinct("userId", query.getQueryObject());
```

But it still giving me the total records.

Comment: What is the **pageable** object?

Comment: //where the populateSortObject() method return the sort object like sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, sortColumn); for the orderBy command.
Sort sort = populateSortObject(sortColumn, sortOrder); 

//the page is the pageNo. and the size is the no. of records per page
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page,size,sort);

Comment: Now it is not clear what you wan to get as a result. The distinct operator returns a list of unique userId strings and can not be mapped to a List<UserDimension>. Try to traverse the result you get with an iterator.

Comment: i want the result in the pagination which returns something like that, 

long total = mongoTemplate.count(query, UserDimension.class); 
  
return new PageImpl<UserDimension>(userDimensionList, pageable, total);